# How do you change the shape of a turtle in Netlogo by mouse-clicking on it?

Tags: netlogo

I am in the midst of a large netlogo project due for school, and have found myself stuck. I am doing a "memory match" type game.

It goes like this: the cards are shown face up to the person playing for 3 seconds, then all the cards change shape to a blue rectangle, or face down. Then, the player is supposed to click on a card, and that changes the cards shape to its corresponding face up shape. If two face-up cards are the same, then they die, and you continue this until there are no cards left on the screen. When that happens, you win!

So my question is, *is it possible to change the shape of a turtle by clicking on it?* My entire project depends on the answer to this question. Any help would be very much appreciated and acknowledged in my code!

*side note: is there a simple way of telling netlogo to kill two turtles if they have the same shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seth has provided you with an answer, but you might find something useful in this example I tried to keep it simple:

```
 globals [all-shapes  score item0 item1]
turtles-own [original-shape]
to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  set-patch-size 100
  resize-world 0 3 0 3
  set-globals
  set-game
  show-items
  play
end
to set-globals
  set all-shapes ["circle" "dot" "tree" "sheep" "box" "bug" "turtle" "x" "circle" "dot" "tree" "sheep" "box" "bug" "turtle" "x"]
end
to play
  set-item1
  set-item2
  if item0 != nobody
  [
    ask item0 [play-the-game]]
end
to reset-shapes
  Set shape  "square"  
  set item0 nobody
  set item1 nobody
end

to set-game
  Ask patches [sprout  1 [set shape "square"  set color blue   set original-shape ""]]
  repeat count turtles / 2[
    ask n-of 2 turtles with [original-shape = ""]
    [ 
      set original-shape item who all-shapes 
    ]
  ] 
end

to show-items
  ask turtles [
    set shape original-shape

  ]
  wait 3
  ask turtles[reset-shapes]
end




to play-the-game
  if item0 != nobody and item1 != nobody and item0 != item1

    [

      ifelse [shape] of item1 = [shape] of item0 and [shape] of item0 != "square" and [shape] of item1 != "square"
        [
          set score score + 1
          ask turtles with [ shape  != "square"] [die]
          reset-shapes
        ]

        [
          reset-shapes
          set score score - 1
        ]

    ]
end

to set-item1
  if mouse-down? and item0 = nobody [
    ask patch mouse-xcor mouse-ycor [

      set item0 min-one-of turtles-here  [ distanceXY mouse-xcor mouse-ycor]
      if item0 != nobody
      [
        ask item0
        [
          set shape original-shape 

        ]]
    ]
  ]
end

to set-item2
  wait 0.1
  if mouse-down? and item0 != nobody and [shape] of item0 != "square" [
    ask patch mouse-xcor mouse-ycor
      [
        set item1 min-one-of turtles-here  [ distanceXY mouse-xcor mouse-ycor]
        if item1 != item0
          [
            ask item1 [set shape original-shape]
          ]
      ]
  ]
end
```

I hope this code get you started:)

This is screenshot of how it works:

[image]

after waiting for 3 seconds :

[image]

and after clicking on 2 turtles with same shape:
[image]

Comment: I have not tested the code thoroughly, so you might find bugs in it.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is going to help a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `go` procedure:

```
  if mouse-down? [
    let candidate min-one-of turtles [distancexy mouse-xcor mouse-ycor]
    if is-turtle? candidate and [distancexy mouse-xcor mouse-ycor] of candidate < 1 [
       ask candidate [ set shape "my new shape" ]
    ]
    ;; wait for the mouse button to be released
    while [mouse-down?] [ ]
  ]
```

In general, if you're trying to write code that uses the mouse, you'll want to look in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library at the models named "Mouse" something: Mouse Example, Mouse Drag One Example, etc.

As for your side note, you should ask it as a separate question.